# ServerException is being thrown while binding RMI service

Tags: java, exception, rmi

I'm trying to build simple echo server as RMI application (step by step as it's described in Sun tutorial).

All source code is shown below, it's very simple:

```
package test;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface EchoServer extends Remote {
    public String sendString (String str) throws RemoteException;        
}
```

---

```
package test;

import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class EchoServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements EchoServer {

    public EchoServerImpl () throws RemoteException {
        super ();
    }

    public String sendString (String str) throws RemoteException {
        return str.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

---

```
package test;

import java.rmi.Naming;

public class RMIServer {

    public RMIServer () {
        try {
            EchoServer eServer = new EchoServerImpl ();
            Naming.rebind ("rmi://localhost:1099/EchoService", eServer); // <--exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RMIServer ();
    }
}
```

I compile code with rmic and I see file EchoServerImpl_Stub.class. After that I run 'rmiregistry' and then I start RMIServer. And at that moment I see ServerException:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.EchoServerImpl_Stub
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:160)
    at test.RMIServer.(RMIServer.java:10)
    at test.RMIServer.main(RMIServer.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:90)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.EchoServerImpl_Stub
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.EchoServerImpl_Stub
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

I think it's a common problem and it's probably connected with wrong deploying. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your *rmiregistry* classpath. The `test.EchoServer` interface needs to be accessible to the *rmiregistry* itself. Set your `CLASSPATH` environment variable before you run up the *rmiregistry* e.g.

```
C:\>set CLASSPATH="MyBinFolder"
C:\>rmiregistry
```

Also, *rmic* is a hangover from before Java 5. It isn't necessary to run it anymore. Just run your server and client as normal and the proxies will be created dynamically.

Regards,
MK

Comment: It *is* necessary to run `rmic` unless you satisfy the conditions mentioned in the preamble to the Javadoc of `UnicastRemoteObject`, which the OP has not done.